# how to use gl_polygon to draw 3d cylinder

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

i am new opengl learner. i know there is build in function to draw cylinder in glut something like

```
GLUquadricObj *quadratic;
quadratic=gluNewQuadric();
gluCylinder(quadratic,0.6f,0.6f,1.5f,20,20);
```

However, is there any other way to draw cylinder using glBegin(GL_POLYGON) and glvertex3d, i am not quite clear about the algorithm behind, please help.

Comment: By the way, never ever use `GL_POLYGON`. A bunch of triangles (`GL_TRIANGLES`, or `GL_QUADS` if you really want) will do, too and doesn't require you to use an individual `glBegin/glEnd` block (or an individual draw call) for each face.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use sin/cos to trace around a circle in segments. Extend those segments upwards with 2 triangles. Then connect them to close the ends.

[image]

You may be able to find the source online for freeglut. Here's some Java code  I found: http://massapi.com/source/lwjgl-source-2.7.1/src/java/org/lwjgl/util/glu/Cylinder.java.html